# Template paramter pack with different types

Tags: c++

Can the following function template be made to actually act based on argument type :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>
#include <typeinfo>
using namespace std;

using UPSTR = unique_ptr<char[]>;

template<typename... Ts>
void uprint(Ts const&... strs){

  auto tp = std::tie(strs...);

  auto& x = std::get<0>(tp);
  if(typeid(x)==typeid(UPSTR)) cout << x.get() << endl;
  // Error : no match for 'operator<<' and 'const std::unique_ptr<char []>') :
  else cout << x << endl;

}

int main(){ 
  UPSTR str = make_unique<char[]>(10); str.get()[0] = 'A';
  uprint(str, "hello");
  return 0;
}
```

?

Error from gcc 12.2 : `no match for 'operator<<' and 'const std::unique_ptr<char []>')`

https://godbolt.org/z/dYG9r7Koj
(MSVC does compile this !)

Comment: The godbolt link compiles if you add `-std=c++20`.

Comment: Not with `uprint("hello", str);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler always instantiates the whole body of a function template, no matter whether some `if` statements can be proven at compile-time to be false. So any syntax/type errors, even in false branches are reported.

But exactly for this use case, there is `if constexpr`:

```
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<std::decay_t<decltype(x)>, UPSTR>)
    cout << x.get() << endl;
else 
    cout << x << endl;
```

- `typeid` is not compile-time construct, `decltype` is.
- `std::decay_t` removes references + constness -> easier matching.

Note that since C++20, `std::unique_ptr` got its `operator<<` which prints its underlying value exactly through `os << x.get()` so `cout<<x;` becomes always valid.

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect ! As per the <<op in C++20, my real code actually does need to distinguish types for way more involved processing than `cout` !

Answer (score 2):

Simply create a helper function with overloads and let overload resolution take care of producing this logic for you. This is much easier to extend and adds logic that can be reused much easier than `if`.

```
template<class T>
void Print(T const& value)
{
    std::cout << value;
}

inline void Print(std::unique_ptr<char[]> const& value)
{
    std::cout << value.get();
}

template<typename... Ts>
void uprint(Ts const&... strs) {

    auto tp = std::tie(strs...);

    auto& x = std::get<0>(tp);
    Print(x);
    std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    auto str = std::make_unique<char[]>(10); str[0] = 'A';
    uprint(str, "hello");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your point about undefined behaviour is incorrect: `make_unique`, unlike `make_unique_for_overwrite`, performs value initialisation. This means `str` initially contains 10 null characters, and `str[1] = '\0'` is a no-op.

Comment: Thank you, that solves the pb. for my example. Didn't think of this obvious solution, because real code passes the arguments to another worker after some processing, so I need them in real type on site.

Comment: @bcsb1001 You're right. I've updated the answer.

Comment: In defense of Fabian, I thought exactly the same thing when I used the (size) constructor for the first time, and had to check the documentation to make sure it's value-initialized (striving for less code).